# When using CRTP how do I declare variable type X in the code below

Tags: c++, crtp

When using CRTP, I am trying to create object based on some config value.
But I am not sure what should be the type that I declare in the main method when calling the Factory create method.

This is the base class for CRTP

```
    template <typename TConfigurationStore>
    class ConfigManager
    {
        public:
        ConfigManager() = default;

        bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "ConfigManager::Configure called.";
            return static_cast<TConfigurationStore*>(this)->Configure(iniReader);
        }            
    };
```

Implementation that we would like to use.

```
    class RedisConfiguration : public ConfigManager<RedisConfiguration>
    {
        public:
        bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "RedisConfiguration::Configure called";
            return true;
        }   
    };
```

Another implemenation...

```
    class FileConfiguration : public ConfigManager<FileConfiguration>
    {
        public:
        bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "EmptyConfiguration::Configure called";
            return false;
        }   
    };
 class ConfigManagerFactory
    {
        public:
        template <typename TConfigurationStore>
        static ConfigManager<TConfigurationStore> *CreateConfigManager(const INIReader& iniReader)
        {
            std::string remoteConfigType = iniReader.Get("RemoteConfiguration", "type", "");
            if (remoteConfigType == REDIS_TYPE_NAME)
            {
                return new RedisConfiguration();
            }


            return new EmptyConfiguration();;
        }

        
        private:
       
        inline static const std::string REDIS_TYPE_NAME {"redis"};
        
    };
```

My question is what should I use in place of X

```
int main()
{

X myconfmgr = ConfigManagerFactory::CreateConfigManager(iniReader);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `auto`?

Comment: I need to pass this myconfmgr in the constructor of another class that will actually use this object. what type should i use in the constructor of another class.

Comment: I'm assuming this is because it's a stripped-down example, but this doesn't even make sense for the CRTP pattern. The derived class's `Configure` function would shadow the CRTP base class' `Configure` -- so you'd never call the base's anyway unless you only hold a reference to it by the base-class (at which point, the lack of a `virtual` destructor will formally be UB if it gets deleted by the base)

Comment: @Human-Compiler so there is no way I could use the CRTP in this case? And the dynamic polymorphism would be the only solution with virtual methods?

Comment: I mean it depends on what else you are hoping to accomplish; CRTP can still be helpful. However, the current code snippets looks like this is an attempt to avoid `virtual` functions while still creating polymorphic behavior -- which might not work quite like you expect. If you invoke the destructor of a base class like `ConfigManager<T>` which does not have a `virtual` destructor (such as through `delete`ing the base), then it's undefined behavior -- even if the derived class has no members. It might _work_, but it's not safe to rely on it.

Comment: yeah thanks, i thought of that as well to get rid of CRTP. But i was curious to know if we can use some kind of decltype(auto) magic etc. but that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Without the caller of `CreateConfigManager()` analyzing the `iniReader` the same way that `CreateConfigManager()` does, it simply has no way to know which template parameter to specify to `CreateConfigManager()`, eg:

```cpp
std::string remoteConfigType = iniReader.Get("RemoteConfiguration", "type", "");
if (remoteConfigType == "redis")
{
    auto myconfmgr = ConfigManagerFactory::CreateConfigManager<RedisConfiguration>(iniReader);
    myconfmgr->Configure(iniReader);
    ...
    delete myconfmgr;
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

The caller should not have to care which type to pass in to the factory.  That defeats the whole point of using a factory in the first place.

I agree with @Human-Compiler in comments.  CRTP really does not make sense for this code.  Simple polymorphism should suffice.

Get rid of the template, make `Configure()` and `~ConfigManager()` be `virtual` in `ConfigManager`, and override `Configure()` in `RedisConfiguration`, `FileConfiguration`, etc. Then `CreateConfigManager()` can return a plain `ConfigManager*` (or better, `std::unique_ptr<ConfigManager>`).

Try this instead:

```cpp
class ConfigManager
{
public:
    ConfigManager() = default;
    virtual ~ConfigManager() = default;

    virtual bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader) = 0;
};

class RedisConfiguration : public ConfigManager
{
public:
    bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader) override
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "RedisConfiguration::Configure called";
        return true;
    }   
};

class FileConfiguration : public ConfigManager
{
public:
    bool Configure(const INIReader& iniReader) override
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "EmptyConfiguration::Configure called";
        return false;
    }   
};

class ConfigManagerFactory
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<ConfigManager> CreateConfigManager(const INIReader& iniReader)
    {
        std::string remoteConfigType = iniReader.Get("RemoteConfiguration", "type", "");
        if (remoteConfigType == REDIS_TYPE_NAME)
        {
            return std::make_unique<RedisConfiguration>();
        }

        ...

        return std::make_unique<EmptyConfiguration>();
    }

private:
    inline static const std::string REDIS_TYPE_NAME {"redis"};        
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto myconfmgr = ConfigManagerFactory::CreateConfigManager(iniReader);
    // this probably should be called inside of CreateConfigManager() instead...
    myconfmgr->Configure(iniReader);
    ...
}
```